# JS - Drag and drop upload - limiting dragged files and allowing click on drop zone to open select files dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have created a file upload system using drag and drop like so:

```js
var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
var upload_button = document.getElementById('submit');
var files_to_upload;

upload_button.onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(files_to_upload==''){
        files_to_upload = document.getElementById('new_file').files;
    }
    upload(files_to_upload);
}
function upload(files){
    var formData = new FormData();
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        formData.append('file[]', files[i]);
    }
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "components/upload.php");
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
dropzone.ondrop = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className = 'dropzone';
    files_to_upload = e.dataTransfer.files;
    var no_uploads = files_to_upload.length;
    this.innerText = no_uploads+' file(s) selected';
}
dropzone.ondragover = function(){
    this.className = 'dropzone active';
    return false;
}
dropzone.ondragleave = function(){
    this.className = 'dropzone';
    return false;
}
```

```css
.dropzone{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  border:3px dashed LightGrey;
  line-height:200px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.dropzone.active{
  border-color:DimGrey;
  color:DimGrey;
}
```

```html
<form class="form mx-auto" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="new_track">Upload Track</label>
<input class="form-control-file" type="file" name="new_file" id="new_file">
</div>

<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">Drop file here to upload</div>

<button class="btn btn-success mt-3" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return false;">Submit</button>

</form>
```

This works fine and does what it is supposed to. However, I want to improve this and have a few questions:

1. How can I limit the drag and drop upload to only allow one file?
2. Rather than the default `<input type="file">` some sites allow users to click on the drop zone instead to open the dialog box to choose files. How would I go about this? (just a point in the right direction would be great)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** How can I limit the drag and drop upload to only allow one file?

**Ans:** Simple solution would be, inside your ondrop function do this:

> ```
> var no_uploads = files_to_upload.length;
> if(no_uploads>1){
> alert("Please upload only one file at a time");
> files_to_upload = '';
>  }
> else
> this.innerText = "your text";
> ```

**2)** Rather than the default  some sites allow users to click on the drop zone instead to open the dialog box to choose files. How would I go about this? (just a point in the right direction would be great)?

**Ans:** Inside your ondrop function do something like this:

> ```
>   if(no_uploads>1){
>   alert("Please upload only one file at a time");
>   files_to_upload = ''; this.onclick = ""; this.style.cursor = "auto";
>    }
>   else{ 
>   this.onclick = your_function_to_view_files(); 
>   this.style.cursor = "pointer"; 
>   this.innerText = "your text"; 
>    }
> ```